# Can I draw more current than an outlet PSU is rated for?

Tags: power-supply, current

I have one 12V wall outlet power supply which can output 500 mA, and another which can output 100 mA.

I would like it to output at least 1A, preferably 2 or 3. Is there any way I can draw that much current, for example by modifying the power supply?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is no.  Power supplies of that kind are designed with a bill-of-materials cost of under a dollar and every component is selected so that it’s sufficient for its job and no more.  If you really wanted to upgrade it you’d have to replace many of the components.  If you want a 3A power supply, by far the simplest approach is to buy one.

Comment: BTW you may get away with a small overload for a short time, eg 700mA for a few seconds, but a massive (6x) overload will hopefully cause it to shut down, otherwise it will burn out very quickly.

Comment: If you want to get one on the cheap, then either look for surplus electronics stores in your area (The US has at least three mail-order stores that are pretty good), or find something that uses a 2 or 3 (or 5) amp 12V brick, and take its brick.  Or go to  rummage/garage/boot/jumble sales (whatever they're called in your country of residence) and search until you find one.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I think I may have a few other old PSUs around, including a 3A one. I’ll see if I can use that.